# Is there a way to remember if a user has competed a survey without being registered?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I have created a simple feedback widget component. This component will be provided via two CDN links to app owners, and it will run on page load. One link is for self(auto)-invocation, and the other one is for manual invocation.
Once users complete the survey, they are expected to close the widget, BUT, if auto-invocation link is used, then on page refresh, the widget would appear again.

What I want to do is to somehow know if this particular user has already completed the survey, and if yes, then I would either not show the widget, or show it in some compact collapsed form.

I am not entirely sure if this is even possible because I am only providing this widget component, which will be used inside other apps. But if anyone has any idea how this could be done, please let me know.

Comment: You need a server somewhere to track that, doesn't have to be dedicated, backend service like Firebase would do.

Comment: A cookie can be saved on the client's side and checks cookies in the auto-invocation page. this is the common way though some users may disable cookies.

Comment: @exudong or maybe save a flag on session storage from the frontend when the user submits the form

Comment: ``sessionStorage`` won't last, it is erased when the user closes the session Tab/Browser. ``localStorage`` is persistent. see [MDN localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: @exudong I used cookies, and it worked but only locally. Now that I published my project to npm, and then set up a CDN link, the cookies are not being set. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I used cookies, and it worked but only locally. Now that I published my project to npm, and then set up a CDN link, the cookies are not being set. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do cookies. I use ``localStorage``. My first thought with cookies would be a security issue; make sure you do HTTP**S**  calls. Also note Google has announced (for several years now) they want to disable **3rd party cookies**. It has been pushed back to 2024 now, but will most likely happen.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I used `localStorage` and it works fine. Do you mind if I ask you one more thing? So, I now have my component in my NPM, and I've created a CDN link for it. Now, what I want is to provide two CDN links. One for auto-invocation, and one for manual. For the auto, I want when the CDN script is read, the component to get invoked itself without the user having to write the tag name in their html. I guess this means the component needs to insert itself into the DOM, but how? For the manual one, I want to provide a function to the users that inserts the component into the DOM.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I created this static method:   `static insertWidget() {
    const widget = document.createElement('ifx-feedback-widget');
    document.body.appendChild(widget);
  }` but I don't know how do I invoke it? When the script is executed, how do I access the component? I can't query it since it's not in the DOM. IF I try to create it, it's empty. So, how do I access it then?

Comment: No no no, don't ask follow up questions in the comments, ask another Stack Overflow question. That way 12265288 other people can answer instead of just me here in the comments.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I've asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77201033/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-stencil-js-web-component-automatically-insert-itself-in

Answer (score 0):

Your component probably doesn't need to know anything about the user. Application logic - e.g. "remembering" whether or not the user has completed the survey - should stay outside of the component - separation of concerns - so the component should probably only be concerned with whether or not it should self-invocate and with notifying the application context about user actions like starting and completing the survey. So you need to create an API for the component that defines how application logic can control it - how it interfaces with the application and how it behaves.

That API could be Stencil properties, methods, and events, or it could be cookies or local storage. There probably isn't a right or wrong way to do it, it just depends on the needs of the component users, which you need to determine. You just need to define what the API is, publish it, and expect applications to use the API as defined.

Comment: I used cookies, and it worked but only locally. Now that I published my project to npm, and then set up a CDN link, the cookies are not being set. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I don't know a lot about cookies, but I know they can be tricky. Domain issues perhaps? Details about how they are set and read would be necessary to debug - probably wise to start a new topic.