# Is there a way to make a Stencil.js web component automatically insert itself into the DOM without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, web-component, stenciljs

I have a small stencil.js component, which I have published to npm, and created a CDN link for it.

The way it normally works is you copy the script with the cdn link, and then you insert the component by its tag name in your html:

```
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/something-feedback@0.0.23/dist/feedback-widget/feedback-widget.esm.js" defer></script>

<ifx-feedback-widget app-name="Some App Name"></ifx-feedback-widget>
```

What I want to do is to make it so that you don't have to write the tag name in your html, but the component to get invoked, i.e. insert itself into the DOM when the script is executed.
The only way I know how to do that is by creating the component yourself, and then inserting it:

```
  <script>
    const myComponent = document.createElement('ifx-feedback-widget')
    document.body.appendChild(myComponent)
  </script>
```

but I don't want to have to do that. Is there a way for the component to insert itself into your DOM when the script is executed without any additional user action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, but technically it's not the component itself that can do it, it's the library.

Your library can include "default" script code that is run when the main library script is loaded. You define that in your `stencil.config.ts` file e.g.:

```
    globalScript: 'src/global/index.ts',
```

And it's contents would be something like:

```
export default function() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const myComponent = document.createElement('ifx-feedback-widget');
        document.body.appendChild(myComponent);
    });
}
```

You may also need to update `src/index.ts`:

```
export * from './components';
export * from './global';
```

You might be able to just add the default function code to `src/index.ts` and point globalScript to that, but I haven't tried that myself whereas I know the above works.

See https://stenciljs.com/docs/config#globalscript

Comment: Thanks, but before I attempt to implement this, would you say that this even recommended? ChatGPT said that it's not recommended for the component to invoke itself. The way it can work right now is the user needs to create the component with `createElement()`, and append it themselves. Would you say this is the more recommended way?

Comment: ChatGPT? Who cares - you will probably get a different answer if you rephrase the question. The component does not invoke itself. A script invokes it. Scripts are often used to initialize all kinds of things in a web page. I recommend that you let your users control that, don't do it automatically, but there is little technical difference - the difference is only in how the component is designed to be used.

Comment: Well, it's a feedback widget that appears at the corner of the screen. It consists of 5 questions + free text, and once submitted, it does not appear again. I use `localStorage` to handle that. I will provide this feedback widget CDN to developers and app owners, and they will just paste it in their apps. They are only required to add the name of their app, and nothing else.

Comment: My initial thought was to provide two CDN links to app owners. One for self-invocation and one for manual invocation. For self-invocation, the idea was that the app owner should not do anything other than paste the link. For manual, the app owner was to invoke it manually. But now that I think about it, self-invocation would not work because the app owner is required to add the name of their app..

Comment: `const myComponent = document.createElement('ifx-feedback-widget')`
    `myComponent.setAttributes('app-name', 'coffeeShop')`
    `document.body.appendChild(myComponent)`

Comment: This is how the app owner must manually invoke or insert the widget component.

Comment: So, what do you think? Is this a recommended approach or?

Comment: A better option would be to use the custom HTML tag in the markdown as designed: `<ifx-feedback-widget app-name="coffeeShop"></ifx-feedback-widget>`.